# Uncaught exception: Client does not respond to 'devise' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5

I am creating a namespaced activeadmin panel named **client** instead of **clients** and have following code in routes

```
devise_for :clients , {
      path: :client,
      controllers: {
          registrations: 'users/registrations',
          confirmations: 'users/confirmations',
          passwords: "active_admin/devise/passwords",
          sessions: "active_admin/devise/sessions",
          unlocks: "active_admin/devise/unlocks"
      },
      path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: "logout", sign_up: "signup" },
      sign_out_via: [*::Devise.sign_out_via, ActiveAdmin.application.logout_link_method].uniq
  }
```

It creates exact routes.

Model of client is

```
def Client < User
end
```

But with following code in our active_admin.rb

```
 config.namespace :client do |_client|
     _client.authentication_method = :authenticate_active_admin_staff!
     _client.current_user_method   = :current_staff
     _client.logout_link_path      = :destroy_staff_session_path
     _client.logout_link_method    = :delete
     _client.root_to               = 'users#index' 
end
```

gives us:

> Uncaught exception: Client does not respond to 'devise' method.

However things work absolutely fine for **clients** namespace. Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: you are using which version of rails?

Comment: Rails 5. @fahadIdrees

Comment: Is this a typo? `def client < User`. Because thats how you declare a method (well kind of since `<` is a syntax error) not a class.

Comment: @max yes its a typo.